# Instagram API limited by server IP not user

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Does anyone have experienced any changes on Instagram API that are limiting access by server IP and not by user?

I have received this message: "Something went wrong: Throttled by Instagram because of too many API requests".

Is this a bug or normal?

Answer (score 1):

That is not bug, and it is normal.
Instagram limits count of certain api calls, and if you call those apis fast enough, then Instagram throws the message "Something went wrong: Throttled by Instagram because of too many API requests".

If you try them after minutes or hours at worst, they will work fine.